# Laplace transfer function and quasi-sinusoidal input

Tags: laplace-transform

Let's suppose we have an LTI system whose Laplace domain transfer function is:
$$
F(s)=\frac{1}{s^2 + \frac{\omega_y}{Q_y}s + \omega_y^2}
$$

Its input is the [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_effect). Such force is experienced if you apply a force to a body along a direction and rotate it along another direction. In our case we move a body of mass $m$ along the $x$ axis:
$$
x(t) = A_d\sin(\omega_dt)
$$
As stated the coriolis force is experienced if you rotate that body, so we also rotate it along $z$ axis:
$$
\Omega=\Omega_0\cos(\omega_st)
$$

Coriolis acceleration is finally:
$$
a_C = 2\Omega\dot{x}=2\omega_dA_d\Omega_0\cos(\omega_st)\cos(\omega_dt)=
\omega_d\Omega_0A_d\Big[\cos[(\omega_d+\omega_s)t]+\cos[(\omega_d-\omega_s)t]\Big]
$$
**along y axis.**

It happens that $F(s)$ is the transfer function that associates acceleration and position along the y axis, it actually is the TF of a mass, spring damper system.

Here comes the question: as you know, if you have a pure sinusoidal function in the time domain and you know its frequency you can compute the output just by calculating $F(s)|_{s=j\omega}$ where $j$ is the imaginary unit. In our case unfortunately this is not so, and my professor just writes:
$$
\overline{y}=\omega_d\Omega_0A_d\cdot F[j(\omega_d\pm\omega_s)]
$$
that's right, that's a $\pm$. We are only interested in the amplitude so the absence of any $\cos$ term is fine. The only hypotesis given till now is:
$$
\text{HP:}\qquad \omega_s\ll\omega_d,\omega_y
$$
He proceeds to make some simplifications using these hypotesis getting to:
$$
\overline{y}\approx\frac{\Omega_0A_d}{2(\Delta_\omega \pm \omega_s)+j\Delta_y}
$$
where:
$$
\Delta_\omega \triangleq \omega_y - \omega_d\\
\Delta_y \triangleq \frac{\omega_y}{Q_y}
$$
and this part is actually easy enough. The only way I can explain the $\pm$ thing is that if $\omega_d=\omega_y$ we are working on the resonance peak of $F(s)$ so for small $\omega_s$ (true) we have $F[j(\omega_d + \omega_s)]\approx F[j(\omega_d - \omega_s)]$, but he then analyzes two different cases, in one of them $\omega_d=\omega_y$ but in the oter $\omega_d\neq\omega_y$.

Is there any math deception I am missing or is my professor a bit inaccurate? He is usually quite rigorous, and quite good at omitting "easy" chunks of his reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

$$F[j(\omega_d + \omega_s)]\approx F[j(\omega_d - \omega_s)]$$ You got it.

Try to insert for the case $\omega_d=\omega_y$, there will be exact cancellations and the  final form should be slightly different.

In that case, you should reconsider the negligibility constraint.

Comment: But isn't that valid only for $\omega_d=\omega_y$? If they are different the transfer function can be quite different in the two points...

Comment: Unless the transfer function is discontinuous, it will not be different at two close points. If it is different, that just means you are not close enough. Or if there is something extraordinary like $\sin (\frac1x)$

Comment: Well it happens to be somewhat discontinuos around $\omega_y$...

Comment: I don't see why it is discontinuous around $\omega_y$ but what matters is if it is discontinuous around $\omega_d$

Comment: It's somewhat discontinuos around $\omega_y$ because there's the resonance peak there, and we are speaking of when $\omega_d = \omega_y$. When they differ (a little) simmetry is lost and quite "violently" since the two points (w+w and w-w) are on the two sides of the peak thath has very high, positive or negative, derivative.

Comment: When I say "around" I mean "exactly at". Also we arent speaking of when $\omega_d=\omega_y$. In that case, you actually insert the function exactly.

Comment: I think the gap between you and me is the gap there is between a mathematician and an aspiring engineer. The transfer function is not discontinuos, but for high $Q_y$ it can become quite discontinuous so that if $\omega_d$ is slightly different from $\omega_y$ the two values of the function can vary a lot. Please have a look back at my question: my teacher uses that 'simplified' formula even when we are in a zone where there is no symmetry at all...